# A library to filter the data in the main home page table (jsp)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have designed a system by using (java, HMTL5, CSS3, JavaScript. JQuery, Struts2, and DB2). in the main page table, I have a button that is suppose to be used for filtering the data based on whatever the user wants to view only in the main page. For example, the user could only view the data that were logged into the system between 3/5/2019 and 4/5/2019, or he/she could be able to filter it by the **Engine System** which falls under the **Related System column**. I heard from a friend that there are libraries that could help me with this kind of data filtering, and I'm wondering if someone could guide me and tell me what should at least I search for on Google so I could get the right libraries or examples that will help me in this.

Please comment below if this question is not clear enough so I could modify at or give more explanation as I'm still new to this world.

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTV3T.png)

Comment: The reason for the close votes is that the question is too open. I personally am a fan of open questions like tool X vs tool Y, given the following evaluation criteria (which tend to be rabidly closed by SO) this questions scope extends this to: Also provide a list of tools given no additional criteria. That said...

Comment: Given this tool set I would use JPA criteria queries. If you are not using JPA then perhaps not. But criteria queries let you programmatically assemble queries. If parameter X was supplied then include that constraint in the query, if parameter Y was supplied... etc.  There are other tools that can help with building SQL queries, if using straight SQL then many template libraries can facilitate this somewhat. By changing the form of the data you can provide it to external tools, tools that work with a DataWarehouse where everything is in a starschema... I doubt that is your intent

Comment: Filtering means by adding creterias programmatically. If you use some widgets for the table where the filtering is already implemented then you can learn from there. Otherwise if it needs to write the filtering api and serialize those filters from the view then better approach is to use json or XML format for the structured data. After parsing such data you have to apply filtering objects to build the query like query by example by it could be much complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

**jQuery fancyTable**

Please visit the below page and you will find JQUERY FANCYTABLE
Enable Sorting, Filtering, And Pagination For Table.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-table-filtering.html